# Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void add(List<String>) from the type List<String>

Tags: apex, trigger

I am getting Method does not exist or incorrect signature in below method at line splitEmail.add(email.split(EMAIL_SEPARATOR))-

```
private static List<String> setAddress(Set<String> emailids) {        

    List<String> emailResults = new List<String>();
    List<String> splitEmail = new List<String>();

    for(String email : emailids) {
       //splitEmail = email.split(EMAIL_SEPARATOR);
       splitEmail.add(email.split(EMAIL_SEPARATOR)); 
    }

    for(String email : splitEmail) {
       emailResults.add(email.trim());
    }

    return emailResults; 
}
```

Why this works `splitEmail = email.split(EMAIL_SEPARATOR)`, but not

```
splitEmail.add(email.split(EMAIL_SEPARATOR))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because to add one list in another we use addAll so you need to do

```
splitEmail.addAll(email.split(EMAIL_SEPARATOR));
```

Split method give us a list and in first case you are assigning it to a list

```
splitEmail = email.split(EMAIL_SEPARATOR);
```

while in second case you are adding it.

[List addALL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_list.htm)